# MVC4 and Session Start does not trigger

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have a MVC 4 application and register a `Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs evt)` in the `Global.asax.cs` class.

Inside the event, I put a logging using NLog. I tested in my local IIS and testing environment, and it works perfectly because the log has been registered.

When we deployed the app in stage environment for QA, the Session_Start event doesn't fire because the log inside the `Session_Start` does not register in the log file even after we restarted the IIS in the stage environment.

Please advise!

Comment: Cold be a directory permission issue (the location where nlog is writing files to). Does IIS process has access to write to that directory ?

Comment: for other events, like Application_AuthenticateRequest, the log file is able to register or write the log. Only this particular Session_Start event, the log is not written to the file, for the rest, it is successful writing to log file, so this is not permission issue, right?

Comment: Do you have `sessionState mode= inproc` in web.config? If not, just add it and try

Comment: putting sessionState in web.config does not help either